# Forcing HTTPS requests in Node.js server on Azure websites

Tags: node.js, azure, express, socket.io, azure-web-app-service

I have Node.js server deployed in IIS on Azure web sites and I want to block or redirect http requests. I use Express + socket.io in my server.

I found 2 ways to do that:

1. in actual socket.io code by [passing allowRequest parameter](https://github.com/socketio/engine.io#methods-1) to socket.io. So my code will look like that :

```js
    var checkRequest = function (req, fn) {
           fn(err, true);
    };

var ioOptions = {
            pingInterval: socketPingInterval,
            pingTimeout: socketPingTimeout,
            path: "/" + config.API_VERSION + "/socket.io",  
            allowRequest : checkRequest
    };

    _socketListener = io.listen(server, ioOptions);
```

The problem is that code never enters checkRequest method, and I don't know why.

2. Add rule to web.config file. I checked several forums, and everybody says that if I add this code:

```html
<rule name="RedirecttoHTTPS">
        <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                <add input="{URL}" pattern="/$" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{SERVER_NAME}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
</rule>
```

It will redirect my hpt requests to HTTPS. But it still works and I can access via HTTP.

What can I try next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Kudu Console](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console), create an `applicationhost.xdt` file in your `d:\home\site` folder, containing the following:

```
  <rewrite xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
    <rules xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
      <rule name="Force HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
          <add input="{WARMUP_REQUEST}" pattern="1" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>    
</system.webServer>
```

And remove whatever you added to your web.config. This should just work.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me with a Node web app in Azure...

https://stpdev.wordpress.com/2015/09/23/force-https-redirection-for-nodejs-apps-hosted-in-azure/

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Force HTTPS" enabled="true">
            <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```